# How to see difference between national and world wonders

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

How can I distinguish world wonders from national wonders from the tech tree or production list? Do I have to go into the help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All National Wonders require you to build a certain improvement in every city you control before you can build them. World Wonders do not.

Mouse over the wonder to view its description. If it includes "requires a foo in all cities", it's a National Wonder.

Additionally, the Artists' Musicians' & Writers' Guilds are also considered National Wonders.

Comment: List of [National Wonders.](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ5/nationalwonders)